# Actual physical length vs points/pixels on excel worksheet

Tags: vba

After reading countless pages of information on the insanely confusing aspect of excel graphics, I feel I have no choice but to ask for help.  My details are as follows:

Applicable system parameters:

- Windows 7 - 64 bit
- Screen res:  1280 x 720, 96 DPI
- Office 10 - 64 bit

Aside from checking configuration in the windows settings, I pulled these values also using API calls.

When I remove all the items from my excel window (ie. scroll bars, etc), application.usablewidth returns 960.  Zoom is constantly at 100%, although this does not change the aforementioned value.

From what I understand, given my DPI settings, 72 points is equivalent to 96 pixels and that should equal to 1 inch, or 2.54 cm.

However, when I draw a line on to the excel spreadsheet (ie. activesheet.shapes.addline(100,100,172,100)), and I use a ruler to measure the length of the line on the screen, it is actually longer by a factor of 1.75x.

Although it is very easy to code in a ratio which would provide an appropriate calibration, I'd like to understand why is it the case?  What am I missing/omitting?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many variables, it's probably impossible to do what you're trying to do reliably.

The key thing you're missing is the physical characteristics of your monitor, those exact settings on a 4" screen would give you a different result to the same settings on a jumbotron.  Not to mention that many monitors allow you to arbitrarily adjust the scale of the output image and the OS would have no idea what had happened.

I suggest you go with your idea of calibrating it, I think it's the only way you'll get it to work..

Comment: Thus, there is no way to programmatically determine enough criteria to undo this mambo jambo?

Comment: Yes, many applications use calibration against a physical object, e.g. a credit card or a certain denomination coin

Comment: Understood, thank you for taking the time to over this with me.